# Add text into rectangle into Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

How do I create text in a rectangle in Tkinter Canvas?
Because, all what I can do is create 2 separate objects.
I have tried doing this:

```py
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="orange")
text = canvas.create_text(50,50,text="Hello, Python!")
```

But those were just 2 objects, which I couldn't move both of them using 1 line of code.
So, how do i it?

Comment: You can add same tag to both of them, then you can move them together using the tag.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?:
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="orange", tag="something")
text = canvas.create_text(50,50,text="Hello, Python!", tag="something")

Comment: Yes, it is what I said.

Comment: Ok! I tested it, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to first create the text, then create the rectangle based on the bbox of the text (so you don't have to guess or hard-code the coordinates). Then, make sure both objects have the same tag. You can then move them together as a unit using the tag.

```
import tkinter as tk

def fall(canvas, tag):
    canvas.move(tag, 0, 1)
    (x1,y1,x2,y2) = canvas.bbox(tag)
    if y1 < canvas.winfo_height():
        # continue to move until it is below the visible area of the canvas
        canvas.after(50, fall, canvas, tag)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text = canvas.create_text(50, 50, text="Hello, Python!", tags=("boxed_text",))
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(canvas.bbox(text), fill="orange", tags=("boxed_text",))
canvas.lower(rect)

# wait for the window to be visible, then start moving the label
canvas.wait_visibility()
fall(canvas, "boxed_text")

tk.mainloop()
```